# Hi all I want to know if they is a shorter cleaner way to my javascript than the code i have here

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a div and called it the selected colour. 
I have lots of divs below this that are my colour swatches. Which ever swatch I click on it will add the class colour of the swatch I clicked on and change the selector colour div to the same and remove which ever previous colour assigned to that class was. my js code is very long and I have only just started learning javascript. I have about 51 colours I have not added all the on click functions as it would be to long. here is my code below Thanks.

```js
function c1(){
 var select = document.getElementById("selectedColour");
 select.classList.remove("cs2", "cs3", "cs4", "cs5", "cs6", "cs7", "cs8", "cs9", "cs10", "cs11", "cs12", "cs13", "cs14", "cs15",
 "cs16", "cs17", "cs18", "cs19", "cs20", "cs21", "cs22", "cs23", "cs24", "cs25", "cs26", "cs27", "cs28", "cs29", "cs30", "cs31", "cs32", "cs33", "cs34",
 "cs35", "cs36", "cs37", "cs38", "cs39", "cs40", "cs41", "cs42", "cs43", "cs44", "cs45", "cs46", "cs47", "cs48", "cs49", "cs50", "cs51");
 select.classList.add("cs1");
}

function c2(){
 var select = document.getElementById("selectedColour");
 select.classList.remove("cs1", "cs3", "cs4", "cs5", "cs6", "cs7", "cs8", "cs9", "cs10", "cs11", "cs12", "cs13", "cs14", "cs15",
 "cs16", "cs17", "cs18", "cs19", "cs20", "cs21", "cs22", "cs23", "cs24", "cs25", "cs26", "cs27", "cs28", "cs29", "cs30", "cs31", "cs32", "cs33", "cs34",
 "cs35", "cs36", "cs37", "cs38", "cs39", "cs40", "cs41", "cs42", "cs43", "cs44", "cs45", "cs46", "cs47", "cs48", "cs49", "cs50", "cs51");
 select.classList.add("cs2");
}

function c3(){
 var select = document.getElementById("selectedColour");
 select.classList.remove("cs1", "cs2", "cs4", "cs5", "cs6", "cs7", "cs8", "cs9", "cs10", "cs11", "cs12", "cs13", "cs14", "cs15",
 "cs16", "cs17", "cs18", "cs19", "cs20", "cs21", "cs22", "cs23", "cs24", "cs25", "cs26", "cs27", "cs28", "cs29", "cs30", "cs31", "cs32", "cs33", "cs34",
 "cs35", "cs36", "cs37", "cs38", "cs39", "cs40", "cs41", "cs42", "cs43", "cs44", "cs45", "cs46", "cs47", "cs48", "cs49", "cs50", "cs51");
 select.classList.add("cs3");
}
```

```html
<div id="colour-codes">
    <div id="selectedColour" class="cs1 cs-selected"></div><p style="display: inline-block; transform: translateY(-10px);">= Selected Colour</p>
  <div class="cs cs1" onclick="c1()"></div>
  <div class="cs cs2" onclick="c2()"></div>
  <div class="cs cs3" onclick="c3()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ community for code reviews

Comment: Try my updated code below. If you have any problems with it leave a comment. If it works for you, accept the answer with the tick below the rating selection on the left of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your JavaScript with the code below. I've condensed the three function into one function that takes the number you want to remain in `classList` as its input. It iterates through the numbers 1 to 51, as you do manually in your code, removing the csNumber strings one by one.

```
function filterCount(filterValue){
  var select = document.getElementById("selectedColour");
  for (i=1; i<52; i++) {
    if (i!=filterValue) {
      select.classList.remove("cs"+filterValue);
    }
  }
  select.classList.add(filterValue);
}
```

To implement this function as you require in your code, call it with the appropriate inputs as so:

```
<div class="cs cs1" onclick="filterCount('1')"></div>
<div class="cs cs2" onclick="filterCount('2')"></div>
<div class="cs cs3" onclick="filterCount('3')"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you been a great help